# IE open remote desktop in full screen mode but doesn't lose focus

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, activex, rdp

I created a simple html page that opens a remote desktop in full screen mode using MsRdpClient ActiveX giving credential automatically.

Everything works fine except that IE doesn't lose focus and the opened remote desktop window stays behind the IE window.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remote Desktop Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="vbscript">
        Username = "my username"
        Server = "server ip address"
        Password = "my password"
        Domain = "my domain"

sub ConnectClient
        MsRdpClient.Server = Server
        MsRdpClient.UserName = Username
        MsRdpClient.Domain = Domain
        MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = Password

        ' false it show inside browser windows 
        MsRdpClient.FullScreen = TRUE
        MsRdpClient.Width = screen.width
        MsRdpClient.Height = screen.height
        MsRdpClient.DesktopWidth = MsRdpClient.Width
        MsRdpClient.DesktopHeight = MsRdpClient.Height

        MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings5.AuthenticationLevel = 2       
        'FullScreen title
        MsRdpClient.FullScreenTitle = L_FullScreenTitle_Text & "(" & Server & ")"

        MsRdpClient.Connect
end sub 
    </script>
    <div id="connectArea">
    <center>
        <object language="vbscript" id="MsRdpClient" classid="CLSID:4eb89ff4-7f78-4a0f-8b8d-2bf02e94e4b2"
            onreadystatechange="ConnectClient" width="1024" height="768">
        </object>                                                  
    </center>                                                   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To try it, copy paste and fill: Username, Password, Domain and Server.

How can I modify it to get remote desktop on top of IE?

**Edit:** More precisely, it opens the remote desktop over IE and after a while IE regains focus.

**After many test:** if I open the url in a new tab in IE, connection is open and IE lose focus, while if I close remote desktop and reload the page in IE, it opens Remote desktop over IE and after a while IE regains focus

**Additional info:** I use IE 11 on Windows 7 Professional, on the server side there is a Windows server 2016

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue when using a Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3-based device. You could try the solution provided by [this fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2708318/fix-internet-explorer-overlaps-a-remote-desktop-session-when-you-conne).

The resolution is downloading the Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Monthly Update from the following Microsoft website: [Windows Embedded CE 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=windows%20embedded%20ce%206.0%20monthly%20update). This update is supported only if all previously issued updates for this product have also been installed.
After you apply this update, you must perform a clean build of the whole platform. To do this, use one of the following methods:

- On the **Build** menu, click **Clean Solution**, and then click **Build Solution**.
- On the **Build** menu, click **Rebuild Solution**.

Comment: 1+ for your time, thanks! for those who use this operating system it is certainly a good answer, unfortunately I use windows 7, but this bug makes me think that even in my case it is a bug, I keep looking for a workaround...

Comment: Thanks for your up vote. Yes, it's more like a bug of OS. You could try to install the updates of the OS to see if the issue can be solved.